# Best way to assign a property to an ALAsset?

Tags: ios, macos, properties, alasset

What would be the best way to assign a property to an existing class?

I have an existing array of ALAssets, and would like to assing a boolean as property to each asset.
I could subclass, but then I have to copy each ALAsset into a new one (?)
I can't create a category, because I need to store that boolean somewhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Associative references, available starting in OS X v10.6, simulate the addition of object instance variables to an existing class. Using associative references, you can add storage to an object without modifying the class declaration.

[Associative References Documentation (developer.apple.com)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html)

Comment: Great answer, works fantastic. Never knew that, really glad that I do now.